# How to join with different fields based on condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I need to join two tables `door_ctrlr_fact` and `equip_store_dim` in my query.

```
select * from door_ctrlr_fact d
join equip_store_dim e
on d.door_id = e.tech_nbr
```

There are a small set of the data with special `door_id`, for example `WM1-1003-072`. The third field in this string has leading zero which needs to be removed before joining. So the query for this subset of data is:

```
select * from door_ctrlr_fact d
join equip_store_dim e
on split_part(d.door_id, '-', 1) = split_part(e.tech_nbr, '-', 1)
and split_part(d.door_id, '-', 2) = split_part(e.tech_nbr, '-', 2)
and trim(leading '0' from split_part(e.door_id, '-', 3)) = trim(leading '0' from split_part(e.tech_nbr, '-', 3))
where door_id like 'WM%'
```

In order to handle all cases, I could just union the two queries based on what `door_id` looks like.

For example, in table `door_ctrlr_fact`:

```
door_id       cycle_cnt
A10003        500
WM4-103-070   1000
B200384       2000
```

In table `equip_store_dim`

```
tech_nbr       store_id
A10003         S001
WM4-103-70    S002
B200384        S004
```

After the join, the result should be:

```
door_id      cycle_cnt       store_id
A10004        500             S001
WM4-103-70    1000            S002
B200384       2000            S004
```

I wonder if there is better way to do it though. Can I use just one query and join the fields differently based on different format of `door_id`

Comment: Please add some sample data and expected output. I believe there should be a more simpler way to achieve this.

Comment: @S-Man Data added

Comment: What is wrong with your first query?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson The first query filters out `WM4-103-070` since it is different than `WM4-103-70` in the second table. However these are considered same by comparing the three fields split by `-` and with leading `0` removed from the third field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the REGEXP_REPLACE function to modify `door_id` in the join, I use groups in the regex to only match a '-0' combo after the second hyphen

```
SELECT door_id, cycle_cnt, store_id
FROM door_ctrlr_fact
JOIN equip_store_dim ON tech_nbr = REGEXP_REPLACE(door_id, '(.*-.*)(-0)(.*)', '\1-\3')
```